# Use Moment to get month of Date object

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I'm sure this is a simple thing but I haven't been able to find the specific syntax in any of the documentation or in any related posts.

In order to get a month-picker to work i need to instantiate a new `Date` object when my controller initializes.

**Controller**

```
scope.date = new Date();
```

This creates a date object with the following format:

> Mon Feb 01 2016 15:21:43 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)

However when I attempt to pull the month from the date object, using moment, I get the error:

> enter code here

**getMonth method**

```
var month = moment().month(scope.date, "ddd MMM DD YYYY");
```

Any idea how to pull the month from the above date object without using substring?

Comment: `moment(scope.date).month()` or `moment(scope.date).format("MMM")`

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can use [`moment.month()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/month/) it will return or set the value.

`moment.month()` is zero based, so it will return 0-11 when doing a get and it expects a value of 0-11 when setting passing a value in.

```
var d = moment(scope.date);
d.month(); // 1
d.format('ddd MMM DD YYYY'); // 'Mon Feb 01 2016'
```

Comment: Even if I change the statement to `var month = moment().month(scope.date);` I still get  the `Invalid Date` error

Comment: You can't set `moment.month()` to a value outside of 0-11, otherwise it won't be a valid month. You're trying to pass a whole date into it. Just create the date with `var d = moment(scope.date)` and then access the month by using `d.month()`

Answer (score 5):

As `moment.month()` returns zero based month number you can use `moment.format()` to get the actual month number starting from 1 like so

`moment.format(scope.date, 'M');`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `moment(scope.date).format("M");`